# Combining seperate rows in a dataframe into one long list

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-lab

I need to edit this code so that I can combine the output into one long list:

```
Expentidure_rate = 0.5
Battery_Size = 100 

    
i = 0
while Updated_DOBS_SUN.iloc[i]["Vehicle"] == "V1":

    
    cols = ["Vehicle", "Expenditure", "Battery_State"]

    V1_Battery_Expenditure = Updated_DOBS_SUN.iloc[i]["Distance"] * Expentidure_rate
    V1_Battery_State = Battery_Size - V1_Battery_Expenditure  #decrement battery state by the expenditure 
    Battery_Size = V1_Battery_State #update battery size for next iteration by updating battery size (technically cheating but it works)
    i += 1
    
    V1_distance_reel = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=range(1))
    
    for a in range(1):
        V1_distance_reel.loc[a].Vehicle = "V1"
        V1_distance_reel.loc[a].Expenditure = V1_Battery_Expenditure
        V1_distance_reel.loc[a].Battery_State = V1_Battery_State

    print(V1_distance_reel)
```

I tried spitting out the output row by row, but for my desired application, I need a long list of all the results combined (Nan rows will be fixed)

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you mean by “combine the output into one long list”? Are you trying to combine the data from multiple rows of a DataFrame into a single list?

Comment: It's unclear what your `Updated_DOBS_SUN` data looks like, or what you're trying to achieve exactly. Please share some example data, and be very clear about how what you need differs from what you currently have? Are you just trying to collect values from `V1_distance_reel` in some list for some reason? You should probably describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, because most of your code seems to be slightly off or doesn't really do that much.